# Getting php array inside a javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple web form that uses a input field using javascript autocomplete array.

The problem im having is I want the javascript autocomplete array to get the php customer first and last name, which would be shown when typing in the web form input text field. Once I click on a name from the autocomplete list I can submit the form. The input text field uses the customer id.

How can I get this to work?

---

### javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

   var currentFocus;

   inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {

   var a, b, i, val = this.value;

   closeAllLists();

   if (!val) { return false;}

   currentFocus = -1;

   a = document.createElement("DIV");

   a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");

   a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

   this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

      b = document.createElement("DIV");

      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

          closeAllLists();
       });
        a.appendChild(b);
       }
      }
     });

 inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {

    currentFocus++;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up

    currentFocus--;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentFocus > -1) {
      /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
      if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
    }
  }
 });
function addActive(x) {

if (!x) return false;

removeActive(x);
if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
}
function removeActive(x) {

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
}
}
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
 }
 }

 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
  }

var customers = ["<?php echo strtoupper($CustomerSet['customer_first'] .'  '. $CustomerSet['customer_last']);?>"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), customers);

</script>
```

---

### php:

```
 <?php

                    foreach ( $this->fetchCustomers[2] as $CustomerSet ) :

                        echo '<option value="'. $CustomerSet['id'] .'" ';

                        if ( $_POST['customerID'] == $CustomerSet['id'] ) :

                            echo ' SELECTED ';

                        endif;

                        echo '>'. strtoupper( $CustomerSet['customer_first'] ) .'  '. strtoupper( $CustomerSet['customer_last'] ) .' - '. $CustomerSet['id'] .'</option>';

                    endforeach;

                ?>
```

---

### html:

```
  <input type="text" name="customerID" id="myInput" placeholder="Select Customer" value="">
```

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: _“How can I get this to work?”_ - start by explaining how it is currently _not_ working as you want it to. Probably not too many people here are inclined to try and find that out themselves by looking at your large un-commented code.

Comment: Just curious why you don't use the shorthand php `<?= $CustomerSet['customer_first']; ?>` Definitely not the main issue here, but smaller files = good.

Comment: just to clarify: you need/want _all_ customers (coming from php somehow) in the js `var customers`, correct? Then a `var customers = <?php echo json_encode($AllCustomers); ?>;` would be the way to go. But I have the slight suspicion you're mixing up serverside with clientside programming.

Comment: Yes your correct, i do want all customers to appear in the var customers list

Comment: ive tried the code `var customers = ["<?php echo $CustomerSet['customer_first'];?>"];` before but i dont get the list of all first names. It only shows me one first name

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look up what "ajax" is, look up some tutorials.

Comment: that's a valid comment, but not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do in 2 separate files.

`index.html`

```
<title>Auto Complete Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" /></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajax({type    : 'POST', 
        url     : 'includes/get-suggestions.php', 
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(msg){
            $('#location').autocomplete({source: msg});
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="location" id="location" style="padding:5px; boarder:0px solid #ccc; border-radius:10px; font-size:14px;" />
```

`get-suggestions.php`

```
$output = [];
foreach ( $this->fetchCustomers[2] as $CustomerSet ) :
    $output[$customerSet['id']] = strtoupper( $CustomerSet['customer_first'] ) .'  '. strtoupper( $CustomerSet['customer_last'] );
endforeach;
echo json_encode($output);
```

It should be working like that.

Additionally sharing that instead of `ajax`, you should go with `jquery` and send a request to php file as I am doing to `includes/get-suggestions.php`.

In that php file, we are just making an array in which ID of record as index and name of customer as value. sending back the response in json format.

In Script code, that json output is mapping in that input field.

Comment: i have the javascript code in a single file and the php/html code in a single file as it already was. I will just make the adjustments to the url and see if this works.

Comment: Does ` #location` call from the `name` or `id` from the `input type`?

Comment: @DashawnThompson yup that can be by any identifier like name, id or type but should be single if for type or class.

Comment: Okay i tried your code but an error is identified on the line that has `$output = [];`

Comment: This didnt work for me

Comment: OK please share files at ping@naveedramzan.com and also db file if you are using.

Comment: Ive managed to get it figured out already

Comment: @DashawnThompson ok that's great.